# Show current date in a view title

Tags: views

Is there a way to insert a PHP date into a title of a view block like so?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solution works and I'm not able to test it right bow, but download and install [views_php](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module. it allows you to add a field which is fill by any php code. so in your views you must select `fields` instead of `content`. search for `php` then you can add this field. in this field try

```
drupal_set_title('TITLE');
```

if this works then you can put your php code there. If not you must modify the template file.

Comment: This worked but I had to change the view title not the global page title. $view->build_info["title"] = "TITLE";. Thanks for the help!